# VueJS - trigger child function

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js

I'm new to using vuejs (2.0). I'm trying to get this functionality down:

- Click a button
- Trigger function in child component
- Increment number in child's data

This is what I currently have

HTML:

```
<div id="root">
    <cart @addtocart="add()"></cart>
    <button @click="$emit('addtocart')">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('cart', {
  template: `<span>{{ items }}</span>`,
  data() {
    return {
      items: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      alert('add');
    }
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  components: ['cart'],
});
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a centralized hub to emit events to (as suggested in the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced), then listen and react to those events inside your child components. Here's a quick update to your code that does that:

```
var eventHub = new Vue();

Vue.component('cart', {
  template: `<span>{{ items }}</span>`,
  data() {
    return {
      items: 0
    }
  },
  created() {
    eventHub.$on('add-item', this.add)
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      alert('add');
      this.items++;
    }
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  components: ['cart'],
  methods: {
    addToCart() {
        eventHub.$emit('add-item')
    }
  }
});
```

I just started using vue myself so I may be wrong but as far as I know, having a child component depend on a specific parent is a bad idea as it forces the child component to be "coupled" to that parent to function and makes it not portable. Emitting events from a child component back up is fine though since that would just be the component letting anyone listening in know that something happened. I guess you could access the parent and the events it has emitted directly by using `this.$parent.$on('add-item', this.method)` but that looks hackish to me. Maybe if your root and child component will always be tightly coupled this way, `this.$parent` would be fine. The "instatiating a new vue instance" example above is probably just another way to do this without making tying your child component up to a parent component since Vue instances implement the event system (thus exposing $emit, $on methods)

Comment: Thank you oh so much. I guess I missed the 'hub' docs. Do you know what the reasoning is behind having to instatiate a vue instance just to communicate between components?

Comment: See my edit above. I'm still learning vue myself so someone might be able to explain this better.

Comment: Nice. This is generally also called `eventBus`.

Comment: be careful to also delete the event listener when child component is unmounter 
`beforeDestroy: function () {
  eventHub.$off('add-item', this.add)
},`

Answer (score 1):

It works great with accessing the `method` with `$children` on the `Parent Vue Component` and it keeps things very simple:

```
<div id="main-component">

   <!-- BUTTON on Main Component that will trigger the method in Child Component -->
   <button @click="$children[0].coolMethod();">I will trigger the a method on Child Component</button>

   <!-- CHILD Component -->
   <some-component-that-has-cool-method></some-component-that-has-cool-method>
</div>
```

**Note:** `$children[0]` because we are referring to the `method` that is at `index 0`.

There are other ways to achieve this and they are described [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/call-child-method-from-parent-vueify/3066/9).

Here's an excerpt from that discussion:

> Much like there is a $parent for a component that is a child of
>   another, there is a children ($children? Can’t quite remember) of
>   child components, but you can just add a ref to your component to make
>   it a bit more clearly perhaps.

Good Luck....

Comment: `$children[0]` is referring to the first child component, not its first method, which makes this a little hacky and unscalable.